# zsh alias not creating file properly

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to change the touch command to create. It needs to take one parameter so I searched up how to do this and I came across creating a function for it. I definitely did not do this right.
Here is my function:

```
create() {
    touch fileName $1
}
```

And I call the function like this

```
create foo.py
```

It does create the file, though the file name includes "fileName".

```
fileName foo.py
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @BubbyBobill : I can't say why you got the downvote - perhaps it is because you could have found the problem by simply reading the _man-page_ for `touch`, and a downvote means that you didn't put much own effort. However, just being curious : What is the advantage of your function _create_ over just using _touch_ directly, except that you have to type one more character...

Comment: I find it hard to remember.

Comment: Understood. You are aware that touch is doing more than just creating a file? If you type `create foo` and the file _foo_ does already exist, the file stays unchanged, but its timestamp is changed. Perhaps a name _create_if_not_already_exists_  or _create_or_modify_time_change_ would be more appropriate than _create_, and easy to remember too.

Comment: No I had no clue thatnk you though, im kind of a noob at this stuff rn

Comment: @BuddyBoblll : _man touch_ will tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `fileName`. That's a placeholder for the file name to create, which in your case is `$1`.

```
create() {
    touch $1
}
```